# What is with this integral: $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac 1x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> ### Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac 1x dx$

Does this integral converge or diverge because if we "just solve it" we get

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac 1x dx = \ln \left| x\right|_{-1}^1=0.$$

But if we do this: $\int_{-1}^0\frac 1x dx + \int_0^1 \frac 1x dx$ it diverges. Why? What really happens here?

Comment: does it helps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value   .I think the integral is left undefined but if you use Cauchy principal value it is$0$.

Comment: As with all integrals, the "limits" doesn't have to converge at the same speed. $\int_{-1}^0\frac{1}{x}\text{d}x$ and $\int _{0}^1\frac{1}{x}\text{d}x$ diverge, so the integral is divergent. But there is "Cauchy's principal value" as stated earlier, when the limits converge at the same speed.

Comment: take a textbook that have theory of improper integrals. Indeed there is a book titled *Improper Riemann Integrals* that cover many topics about these integrals. In particular it shows that, in general, it is a mistake to use a "primitive" as you did in you false identity.

Comment: [Blackpenredpen](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dHwrzLDmdT8) made a video on this, which does not really answer your question, but the comments are worth reading through :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out, since no-one has yet, that the connection between integrals (area under curves) and differentiation is a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The particular theorem being used here requires that the integrand, $\frac{1}{x}$, be continuous over the domain, in this case, $[-1, 1]$. The great big asymptote in the middle of this interval suggests that the FTC simply doesn't apply, and any conclusions you get are erroneous.

Comment: _Technically_, the indefinite integral / antiderivative / primitive of $\frac1x$ isn't $\ln |x|$. It isn't even $\ln |x|+C$. It's $\ln|x|+C(x)$ where $C(x)=C_1$ for $x<0$ and $C(x)=C_2$ for $x>0$, for two real numbers $C_1,C_2$.

Comment: @Arthur Of course $\ln |x|$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$. What you mean is probably that not every antiderivative is of the form $\ln |x| + C$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Adayah Note the "the" in there. $\ln|x|$ is _an_ antiderivative, but it isn't _the_ antiderivative (not that there is such a thing as "the antiderivative", but I often see that phrase used when people are actually talking about "the _collection of_ antiderivatives"). That was my point.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600482/symmetric-integral-of-1-x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot apply the fundamental theorem of calculus since the function $$\frac{1}{x}$$ is not defined on the interval $[-1,1]$. Split the integral in the following way
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}+\int_{-1}^0\frac{dx}{x}$$

Now you can apply the following theorem

> Let $a$ be a real, then $$\int_0^a \frac{1}{x^\alpha}dx$$ converges if and only if $\alpha<1$.

Hence both integral diverge, then the sum of them diverges.

Comment: I'm sorry to replicate such an old problem, but I think there's a typo. This should say that the integral converges if and only if $\alpha<1$, otherwise we can take $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t^{2}}dt$ which does not converge as a counterexample.

Comment: @A.P. Thanks! I corrected the typo!

Answer (score 2):

This is an improper integral. It is defined as$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_\varepsilon^1\frac1x\,\mathrm dx+\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^-}\int_{-1}^\varepsilon\frac1x\,\mathrm dx$$if both limits exist. In this case, none of the limits exist (in $\mathbb R$).

Answer (score 0):

For $[a,b]$ an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, let $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $F\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is an *antiderivative* of $f$ on $[a,b]$ if $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. It will be necessarily so in $(a,b)$, while left continuous at $a$: $F(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+} F(x)$, and right continuous at $b$: $F(b)=\lim_{x\to b^-} F(x)$ .

If $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ has an antiderivative $F$ on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable and so we have the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

The integral in the question is *improper* in the sense that the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is unbounded over the limits of integration $[-1,1]$, namely at the problem spot $x=0$ where it cannot be continuously defined, with the branch of the hyperbola to the left of $x=0$ an asymptote to negative $y$-axis, the branch of the hyperbola to the right of $x=0$ an asymptote to positive $y$-axis. Therefore you cannot invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus over $[-1,1]$ in the manner you have done as you integrate over a discontinuity.

As an example of something that looks like it shouldn't integrate but does consider $g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$; at the singular point $x=0$ we have the indeterminate expression $\frac{0}{0}$, but we know
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$
and so $g(x)$ is continuous, having $g(0)=1$, and is bounded over $[-1,1]$.