# Divergent Integral?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-integrals

Why is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx$$

divergent, when the function being described is clearly an odd function and $$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx = 0$$
for any finite a?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180239/why-isnt-an-odd-improper-integral-equal-to-zero).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493443/what-is-the-intuition-behind-why-the-integration-of-fx-x-for-closed-interv

Comment: Why is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xdx$$
divergent, when the function being described is clearly an odd function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Cauchy principle value is indeed $0$:
$$\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\int_{-\ell}^\ell\frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx=0,$$
as the integrand is odd and hence the integral is zero for all values of $L$, as you noted. However, if one of the limits of integration goes to infinity faster than the other, the integral may not be finite. For example:
$$\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\int_{-\ell}^{\exp\ell}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx=\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\log(\exp2\ell+1)-\log(\ell^2+1),$$
which doesn't exist. Since the integral's convergence depends on the speed at which your bounds go to infinity, we say the integral diverges. Contrast this with the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
Let $f$ and $g$ be functions which approach $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Then: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{-g(x)}^{f(x)}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\tan^{-1}\big(f(x)\big)-\tan^{-1}\big(-g(x)\big)=\pi/2+\pi/2=\pi$$
for any such $f$ and $g$ (probably under some assumptions that they are nice enough).

Comment: but here limits are just numbers not functions

Comment: @TheStudent functions are necessary in order to capture the idea of "going to infinity" at different rates. It doesn't make sense to talk about numbers approaching infinity

Comment: what if limit is finite? i.e instead of -infty and infty it is a,-a

Comment: @TheStudent then the integral is defined normally, and we don't need to appeal to functions in the limits of integration (unless there are poles at the boundaries and the integral is improper again). The issue of functions arises when we need to take limits with the bounds of integration, and limits are defined using functions, so we're forced to appeal to them.

Comment: The upper and lower limits do not even need to be related.  For an improper integral of the type in the OP to converge one needs to have the following double limit converge $$ \lim_{(L,U)\to (-\infty,\infty)} \int_{L}^{U} f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: *Principal* value, not principle.